# When writing a category, should i use self or the category name

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

When writing a NSString category/extension, does it matter if i use

```
return [self stringWithFormat:units[i], value/10.0];
```

or

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:units[i], value/10.0];
```

is there an advantage to using `self` or is this one of those user preferences things

Comment: `self` indicates instance methods (at least for me), but stringWithFormat is a static method, therefore use `[NSString ...]`.

Comment: @luk2302 `self` refers to the current class in a class method.

Comment: @RobNapier therefore I wrote "indicates", I added a clarification

Comment: @luk2302 so if im understanding correctly, use self for (-) methods and NSString for (+) methods?

Comment: You should probably do whatever Rob advices since I do not have as much experience as he does and have not encountered and situations where `self` was a bad choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I assume that the extension method in question is a class method. There seems to be some confusion that's leading to down votes; this is a very good question.)*

As a general rule, you should use `self` here. That way if a subclass has overridden the method, you will use the subclass's version of that method. Subclasses can override class methods just like they can override instance methods.

That said, `NSString` is a kind of funny case because it's a class cluster, and so it would be very surprising for any of its hidden subclasses to override this class method (and subclassing it yourself is tricky at best). So in practice, for `NSString`, it almost certainly doesn't matter. But as a rule, you have the right intuition: use `self` unless you explicitly *don't* want to use the subclass's implementation.

There is one big exception to this: `+initialize`. You need to be very thoughtful about what class you're in, because this may be called multiple times. If you're overriding `+initialize`, see its documentation about how to implement it properly.

Comment: for the most part, im just writing extensions to take a string and parse it to a specific format, for example a currencyWithChange, numberWithoutDecimal, etc...  `use self unless you explicitly don't want to use the subclass's implementation.` was what i needed to hear, thanks